# how to validate form in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When i submit the form alert will be show but after page is redirect.

i have call function to the submit button on click.
alert will show and after form will be submited
please give me idea to validate form

```
function companyFormValidation()
    {
        var name    = document.getElementById('companyname').value;
        var title   = document.getElementById('companytitle').value;
        var desc    = document.getElementById('description').value;
        var logo    = document.getElementById('logo').value;
        var email   = document.getElementById('emailid').value;
        var website = document.getElementById('siteurl').value;
        var phonenumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber').value;
        var faxNumber   = document.getElementById('faxNumber').value;
        var address     = document.getElementById('address').value;
        var latitude    = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
        var longitude   = document.getElementById('longitude').value;

        if(name == '')
        {
            alert('Name can not empty');
            //$("#ename").html("Name can't be empty..");

        }
    }



<form id="addCompanyForm" method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal" >
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Company </legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyname" id='companyname' />
                                    <div id="ename"></div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companytitle" id="companytitle" />
                                    <div id="etitle"></div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id = "description"></textarea>
                                <div id="edesc"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Logo</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name='logo' id="logo" >
                                        <!-- <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                                Browse&hellip; <input type="file" name="">
                                            </span>
                                        </span> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailid" id="emailid"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Website</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="siteurl" placeholder="http://" id="siteurl" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Fax number</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="faxNumber" id="faxNumber" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Address</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Latitude</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="latitude" id="latitude" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Longitude</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="longitude" id="longitude" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="companyFormValidation()" >Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: I would like to use jquery library http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code with return false if any field is empty.

```
 <script>
    function companyFormValidation()
        {
            var name    = document.getElementById('companyname').value;
            var title   = document.getElementById('companytitle').value;
            var desc    = document.getElementById('description').value;
            var logo    = document.getElementById('logo').value;
            var email   = document.getElementById('emailid').value;
            var website = document.getElementById('siteurl').value;
            var phonenumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber').value;
            var faxNumber   = document.getElementById('faxNumber').value;
            var address     = document.getElementById('address').value;
            var latitude    = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
            var longitude   = document.getElementById('longitude').value;

            if(name == '')
            {
                alert('Name can not empty');
                //$("#ename").html("Name can't be empty..");
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>

    <form id="addCompanyForm" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return companyFormValidation()" class="form-horizontal" >
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Company </legend>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyname" id='companyname' />
                                        <div id="ename"></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companytitle" id="companytitle" />
                                        <div id="etitle"></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id = "description"></textarea>
                                    <div id="edesc"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Logo</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name='logo' id="logo" >
                                            <!-- <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                                    Browse&hellip; <input type="file" name="">
                                                </span>
                                            </span> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email </label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailid" id="emailid"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Website</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="siteurl" placeholder="http://" id="siteurl" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Fax number</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="faxNumber" id="faxNumber" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Latitude</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="latitude" id="latitude" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Longitude</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="longitude" id="longitude" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  >Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Your code is written in js and you are asking for jquery. For jquery use above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use validate JS "jquery.validate.min.js" for jquery validation. It's a simple. You want the demo you can check it http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/. Hope this helps to you, Thanks!